# From given two lists, how to extract all the elements from one list that are not available in the other list in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-editor, dart-2, dartdoc

I have two lists in Dart as below,

```
  final List availableIssueComponents = [
    {'id': 1, 'componentName': 'Cash Acceptor'},
    {'id': 2, 'componentName': 'Printer'},
    {'id': 3, 'componentName': 'PIN Pad'},
    {'id': 4, 'componentName': 'Key Board'},
    {'id': 5, 'componentName': 'Touch Screen'},
    {'id': 6, 'componentName': 'Computer'},
    {'id': 7, 'componentName': 'Application'},
    {'id': 8, 'componentName': 'Network'},
    {'id': 9, 'componentName': 'Power'},
    {'id': 10, 'componentName': 'Camera'},
    {'id': 11, 'componentName': 'Safe'},
    {'id': 13, 'componentName': 'Screen'},
    {'id': 14, 'componentName': 'Battery'},
    {'id': 15, 'componentName': 'Ports'},
    {'id': 16, 'componentName': 'Application'},
    {'id': 17, 'componentName': 'Safe'},
    {'id': 18, 'componentName': 'Camera'},
    {'id': 19, 'componentName': 'Power'},
    {'id': 20, 'componentName': 'Key Board'},
    {'id': 21, 'componentName': 'PIN Pad'},
    {'id': 22, 'componentName': 'Printer'},
    {'id': 23, 'componentName': 'Computer'},
    {'id': 24, 'componentName': 'Touch Screen'},
    {'id': 25, 'componentName': 'Application'},
    {'id': 26, 'componentName': 'Network'}
  ];

  final List selectedIssueComponents = [
    {'id': 3, 'componentName': 'PIN Pad'},
    {'id': 6, 'componentName': 'Computer'},
    {'id': 19, 'componentName': 'Power'},
  ];
```

**From the above two lists, I am trying to select all the elements from the `availableIssueComponents` excluding the elements that are already available in the `selectedIssueComponents`.**

Ex: Since components with ids of `3`, `6`, `19` are common in both the lists, I would want a third list that contains all the components excluding the components with the ids of `3`, `6`, `19`.

The third list should look like below,

```
  final List availableIssueComponents = [
    {'id': 1, 'componentName': 'Cash Acceptor'},
    {'id': 2, 'componentName': 'Printer'},
    {'id': 4, 'componentName': 'Key Board'},
    {'id': 5, 'componentName': 'Touch Screen'},
    {'id': 7, 'componentName': 'Application'},
    {'id': 8, 'componentName': 'Network'},
    {'id': 9, 'componentName': 'Power'},
    {'id': 10, 'componentName': 'Camera'},
    {'id': 11, 'componentName': 'Safe'},
    {'id': 13, 'componentName': 'Screen'},
    {'id': 14, 'componentName': 'Battery'},
    {'id': 15, 'componentName': 'Ports'},
    {'id': 16, 'componentName': 'Application'},
    {'id': 17, 'componentName': 'Safe'},
    {'id': 18, 'componentName': 'Camera'},
    {'id': 20, 'componentName': 'Key Board'},
    {'id': 21, 'componentName': 'PIN Pad'},
    {'id': 22, 'componentName': 'Printer'},
    {'id': 23, 'componentName': 'Computer'},
    {'id': 24, 'componentName': 'Touch Screen'},
    {'id': 25, 'componentName': 'Application'},
    {'id': 26, 'componentName': 'Network'}
  ];
```

I tried to do this using Sets and the following was my approach,

```
Set availableComponentsSet = Set.from(availableIssueComponents);
Set issueComponentsSet = Set.from(selectedIssueComponents);

Set resultComponents = availableComponentsSet.difference(issueComponentsSet);
```

But when logged to the console it `resultComponents` contained all the components. Which is not what I wanted. I also tried nested for loops and it did not work either.

Comment: Why its not working: Your List is a List<Map<String,dynamic>> and Set uses '==' to test equality. In Dart comparing Maps with == is only true if they're the exact same Map - it will be false if you compare two different maps with the same content. To compare map contents for equality you need to use MapEquality() or DeepCollectionEquality(). I don't know an elegant solution, but there's likely a way to create a List generator of some sort that will let you supply a function where you can test equality. List.where() or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The components objects are not filtered by the `Set` when using a `Set<Map>` because `Map` is a reference type and is considered unique unless the two objects being compared are pointing at the same instance (as @Pat9RB commented).

I would map the selected IDs to a list, then filter out those IDs using [`List#where(fn)`](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables#filtering)

```dart
final availableIssueComponents = [
  {'id': 1, 'componentName': 'Cash Acceptor'},
  {'id': 2, 'componentName': 'Printer'},
  {'id': 3, 'componentName': 'PIN Pad'},
  {'id': 4, 'componentName': 'Key Board'},
  {'id': 5, 'componentName': 'Touch Screen'},
  {'id': 6, 'componentName': 'Computer'},
  {'id': 7, 'componentName': 'Application'},
  {'id': 8, 'componentName': 'Network'},
  {'id': 9, 'componentName': 'Power'},
  {'id': 10, 'componentName': 'Camera'},
  {'id': 11, 'componentName': 'Safe'},
  {'id': 13, 'componentName': 'Screen'},
  {'id': 14, 'componentName': 'Battery'},
  {'id': 15, 'componentName': 'Ports'},
  {'id': 16, 'componentName': 'Application'},
  {'id': 17, 'componentName': 'Safe'},
  {'id': 18, 'componentName': 'Camera'},
  {'id': 19, 'componentName': 'Power'},
  {'id': 20, 'componentName': 'Key Board'},
  {'id': 21, 'componentName': 'PIN Pad'},
  {'id': 22, 'componentName': 'Printer'},
  {'id': 23, 'componentName': 'Computer'},
  {'id': 24, 'componentName': 'Touch Screen'},
  {'id': 25, 'componentName': 'Application'},
  {'id': 26, 'componentName': 'Network'}
];

final selectedIssueComponents = [
  {'id': 3, 'componentName': 'PIN Pad'},
  {'id': 6, 'componentName': 'Computer'},
  {'id': 19, 'componentName': 'Power'},
];

final selectedIds = selectedIssueComponents.map((component) => component['id']).toList();
final filtered = availableIssueComponents.where((element) => !selectedIds.contains(element["id"])).toList();

print(filtered);
```

If you prefer to use `Set` and `difference` you could create sets of the ids. This would create a set of `int` (`Set<int>`) which is a primative type and would allow the type of filtering expected:

```dart
final availableIssueComponents = [
  {'id': 1, 'componentName': 'Cash Acceptor'},
  {'id': 2, 'componentName': 'Printer'},
  {'id': 3, 'componentName': 'PIN Pad'},
  {'id': 4, 'componentName': 'Key Board'},
  {'id': 5, 'componentName': 'Touch Screen'},
  {'id': 6, 'componentName': 'Computer'},
  {'id': 7, 'componentName': 'Application'},
  {'id': 8, 'componentName': 'Network'},
  {'id': 9, 'componentName': 'Power'},
  {'id': 10, 'componentName': 'Camera'},
  {'id': 11, 'componentName': 'Safe'},
  {'id': 13, 'componentName': 'Screen'},
  {'id': 14, 'componentName': 'Battery'},
  {'id': 15, 'componentName': 'Ports'},
  {'id': 16, 'componentName': 'Application'},
  {'id': 17, 'componentName': 'Safe'},
  {'id': 18, 'componentName': 'Camera'},
  {'id': 19, 'componentName': 'Power'},
  {'id': 20, 'componentName': 'Key Board'},
  {'id': 21, 'componentName': 'PIN Pad'},
  {'id': 22, 'componentName': 'Printer'},
  {'id': 23, 'componentName': 'Computer'},
  {'id': 24, 'componentName': 'Touch Screen'},
  {'id': 25, 'componentName': 'Application'},
  {'id': 26, 'componentName': 'Network'}
];

final selectedIssueComponents = [
  {'id': 3, 'componentName': 'PIN Pad'},
  {'id': 6, 'componentName': 'Computer'},
  {'id': 19, 'componentName': 'Power'},
];
final availableIds = availableIssueComponents.map((component) => component['id']).toSet();
final selectedIds = selectedIssueComponents.map((component) => component['id']).toSet();
final filteredIds = availableIds.difference(selectedIds);
final filteredComponents = availableIssueComponents.where((element) => filteredIds.contains(element["id"])).toList();

print(filteredComponents);
```